# How can I exclude first <tr>

Tags: php, dom

With php dom, I am getting all TRs and TDs inside.

```
<?PHP
foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
   echo $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue);
}
?>
```

Can we exclude the first tr and its tds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the node list is numerically indexed (though I cannot test it), so using a key in the foreach may work:

```
foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $key => $tr){
   // Don't act on the first element
   if ($key > 0) {
     echo $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bad method but works :

```
<?PHP
$first = false;
foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr){
   if($first){
     echo $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue);
   }
 $first = true;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the index of elements, if its first and use `continue` the to skip the loop.

```
<?PHP
foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $index => $tr){
   if($index == 0) { continue; }
   echo $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue);
}
?>
```